# Does someone in here knows how to rewrite this in C# for an UWP application?

Tags: pi-3, i2c, windows-iot, c#

```
import struct
import smbus
import sys

def readVoltage(bus):

"This function returns as float the voltage from the Raspi UPS Hat via the provided SMBus object"
address = 0x36
read = bus.read_word_data(address, 2)
swapped = struct.unpack("<H", struct.pack(">H", read))[0]
voltage = swapped * 78.125 /1000000
return voltage


def readCapacity(bus):
"This function returns as a float the remaining capacity of the battery connected to the Raspi UPS Hat via the provided SMBus object"
address = 0x36
read = bus.read_word_data(address, 4)
swapped = struct.unpack("<H", struct.pack(">H", read))[0]
capacity = swapped/256
return capacity


bus = smbus.SMBus(1)  # 0 = /dev/i2c-0 (port I2C0), 1 = /dev/i2c-1 (port I2C1)

print "Voltage:%5.2fV" % readVoltage(bus)

print "Battery:%5i%%" % readCapacity(bus)




# draw battery

n = int(round(readCapacity(bus) / 10));

print "----------- "

sys.stdout.write('|')

for i in range(0,n):

sys.stdout.write('#')

for i in range(0,10-n):

sys.stdout.write(' ')

sys.stdout.write('|+\n')

print "----------- "


if readCapacity(bus) == 100:

print "Battery FULL"

if readCapacity(bus) < 20:

print "Battery LOW"
```

## This is what i have tried so far, But i only get 255 255 255 in every byte in return from the UPSHat.Read(ReadBuf)....

```
public class BatteryReporter
{
    private const int UPS_SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x36;

    private I2cDevice UPSHat { get; set; }
    private double voltage { get; set; }
    private double capacity { get; set; }

    public BatteryReporter()
    {
        InitSensor();
    }

    public byte[] GetVoltage()
    {
        byte[] ReadBuf = new byte[7];
        UPSHat.Read(ReadBuf);
        return ReadBuf;
    }

    public string GetCapacity()
    {
        return "TODO";
    }

    private async void InitSensor()
    {
        var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(UPS_SLAVE_ADDRESS);
        string aqs = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
        var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
        UPSHat = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id, settings);

    }

}
```

Comment: You sure that `dis[0]` is the correct device?? It could be a blank device or a reserved bus device and not the actual device you think it is. The code looks OK to me.. just that hard codded array is always a question point. What other entries are in the array?

Comment: Have you tried `string aqs = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector("I2C1");` ?

Comment: I had the correct device selected. the problem was that i didn't tell what data i wanted. I'm new to this I2C communication. I will answer my question with the correct code. Maybe have more people out there that want to use this RASP USP HAT with windows 10 iot.

Comment: Could you explain why you wanted to write this in C#?  Asking because I love C# and I want to get better with Raspberry Pi, so seeing something about their intersection's neat.  For example, does C# run on Raspberry Pi now (via .NET Core, I'd guess?), or is this meant to communicate with an external Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I'm  studying to be an system developer with c# as primary language.  And the rasberry pi's is one of my big hobby. You can download windows 10 IOT free and put in on a sd card and just start the raspberry.  And then start developing UWP apps. Uploading with the network cable. And you can also debugging.  It's very fun! You have to try it now. 

Comment: Here you have. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I'm new to this I2C communication, but it's really fun. I forgot to write the adress for what data i want. Here is my code that is now working. =)

```
public class BatteryReporter
{
    private const int UPS_SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x36;
    private byte[] command = new byte[1];
    private byte[] voltData = new byte[2];
    private byte[] capacityData = new byte[2];

    private I2cDevice UPSHat { get; set; }

    public BatteryReporter()
    {
        InitSensor();
    }

    private async void InitSensor()
    {
        var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(UPS_SLAVE_ADDRESS);
        string aqs = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
        var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
        UPSHat = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id, settings);
    }

    public double GetVoltage()
    {
        command[0] = 0x02;
        UPSHat.WriteRead(command, voltData);
        var rawVoltReading = voltData[0] << 8 | voltData[1];
        double voltReading = Math.Round(rawVoltReading * 78.125 / 1000000,2);
        return voltReading;
    }

    public double GetCapacity()
    {
        command[0] = 0x04;
        UPSHat.WriteRead(command, capacityData);
        var rawCapacityReading = capacityData[0] << 8 | capacityData[1];
        double capacityReading = rawCapacityReading / 256;
        return capacityReading;
    }
}
```